# procmailrc and php

Tags: procmail

This doesn't work.
It's supposed to email me.(as a test; what we really want the php file to do is insert into a mySQL database table)

The input is a payment notification message from PayPal.

(A similar recipe *does* find the Description line and mails it to two of us)

the procmailrc:

```
VERBOSE=off
MAILDIR=/usr/home/our/mail
LOGFILE=/usr/home/our/paypal.log
EXITCODE = 99

:0b
|base64 -d|grep -i Description|php tp129.php
```

---

the php file:

```
$rawmessage = "";
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
while(!feof($fd)) {
$rawmessage .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

$msg129 = 'raw is ' .$rawmessage;

mail('myaddress@myisp.com','msg129',$msg129 );
```

Comment: At a high level, I'm concerned that you may end up in an infinite mail loop.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things you might want to fix:

1. Check your `$HOME/.forward` file. I think it has to have 644 permissions, and contain a single line: `"| /usr/bin/procmail"` to get `procmail` to do things with your email. Check the actual path to `procmail` - it may be `/bin/procmail` or something else on your system. Supposedly you have to have the fully qualified path to `procmail` in `.forward`.
2. Put `<?php` on the first line of the file `tp129.php` Also, your pipeline may need to have the full path to the `php` interpreter, `/usr/bin/php` or whatever.
3. Double check the params in `.procmailrc`. The file names in `MAILDIR=/usr/home/our/mail` and `LOGFILE=/usr/home/our/paypal.log` seem fishy. That is, `/usr/home/` is a strange directory. User ID's "home" directories are usually in `/home` or `/u`, very rarely if ever under `/usr` any more.
4. Run the PHP code by itself: `php tp129.php`, and then type some text in, any text, then ctrl-D.  Does that send email to the desired address(es)? If not, fix whatever causes that.

Comment: ls -l .f*
-rw-------  1 bcp  users  59 Mar 16  2006 .forward

Comment: Hi, @Bruce Ediger  ls -l .f*
-rw-------  1 bcp  users  59 Mar 16  2006 .forward  Is that OK? The php file is
 alright, works fine if one pipes in text. The procmailrc is called  paypal.rc pwd  gives  /usr/home/bcp  Sorry, pressing Enter here seems to end the message?  Thanks for your help.  Please tell me any more info I can supply, and/or any ideas to try.

Comment: OK, `pwd` says that, but what does `echo $HOME` say? And I think the file has to be named `.procmailrc` for the `procmail` process to find it. `procmail` may run with a very small `PATH` - is `php` in a directory in `$PATH`? My `.procmailrc` file has 644 permissions, somethings things get picky about that (`sshd`, for instance).

Comment: ~> echo $HOME
/usr/home/bcp
~> echo $PATH
/usr/home/bcp:/usr/home/bcp/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/games:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:.
~> which php
/usr/local/bin/php  It is 644

Comment: If you have a log file `/usr/home/our/paypal.log`, that should already show whether Procmail is running.  I assume it is, and that the log file will actually contain information which shows you what's actually wrong (namely, that PHP does not send the message because it's malformed; or, possibly, that the script is being executed as a shell script, and thus producing dire syntax errors).

Answer (score 0):

The PHP `mail()` function requires a valid email message, with full headers.  It looks like your code only produces a mail body (unless the decoded base64 content contains the headers; but even then, adding an arbitrary string in front of them would wreck that message).

Your explicit assignment of `EXITCODE` would terminate Procmail with an error message if it weren't for the fact that it contains a syntax error.  In shell script, and thus also in Procmail, you are not allowed whitespace around an equals sign in an assignment.  It's unclear what you hope to achieve with the `EXITCODE` anyway; my suggestion is simply to leave it out.

Given that your final goal is to import the message to MySQL, I would propose a simpler test: Open a second file for appending, and write the output there.  This should show you whether the PHP code is working as you expect.  (Maybe add a time stamp so you see when the results were written, so you don't end up examining old results. Perhaps you'll actually want to overwrite instead of append as long as you're testing; but the date stamp still makes sense.)  If PHP is your tool of choice, feel free to stick with that, although I suspect this would be much simpler as a tiny shell script, which you could probably inline to your `.procmailrc`. Depending on your database schema, something like

```
:0b
| base64 -d | \
  sed -n '/Description/s/.*/insert into table (field1,field2,field3) values (&);/p' \
  | mysql -uyou -pxyzzy -s db
```

In the meantime, here's how I would solve your immediate problem.

The entire PHP program can be replaced with a single piece of sed script: `sed '1s/^/raw is /'` though to avoid a [useless use of `grep`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) I would also factor in the search for `Description`.

```
:0bfw   # Can be simplified if your sed supports a case-insensitive flag
| base64 -d | \
  sed -n '/[Dd][Ee][Ss][Cc][Rr][Ii][Pp][Tt][Ii][Oo][Nn]/s/^/raw is /p'
:0
! myaddress@myisp.com
```

The forwarding action will retain the original headers.  If that's not what you want, maybe extract the ones you do want to keep, e.g. with `formail`; or create entirely new headers with `printf`.  You could replace the simple second recipe with the action `! myaddress@myisp.com` with something a bit more complex, like perhaps the following:

```
:0fhw
| ( formail -XSubject:; \
    printf "From: %s\nTo: %s\n" "myaddress@myisp.com" "myaddress@myisp.com" )
:0
! -t
```

(`sendmail -t` means take whatever the headers of the message say, and send the message there.)

For debugging, your recipe file should not contain an explicit `VERBOSE=off`.  This is the default, which makes no sense to override; but hard-coding it makes it impossible to debug your recipes with `VERBOSE=yes` on the Procmail command line.